# Send volume command when simulated headset

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headset

I use that example to setup my computer as a simulated headset:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205378/use-desktop-as-bluetooth-headset

It works properly, I can connect my smartphone to my computer and I ear the sound generated by it.

Now I want to send volume up,down/ play/pause command. Is there a way to do that with bluetoothctl ?